# Views vs upvotes score for questions/answers?

Tags: support, statistics

I'm interested in seeing the views vs upvotes of an answer or question.  Does a query exist for this?

For example:

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array) has 469538 views and 8428 upvotes, yielding **0.0179%**.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121146/reading-ghc-core) has 7620 views 113 upvotes, yielding **0.0148%**

(No affiliation to either question.) The first question might be more "interesting" due to its higher percentage.

Also, is it possible to differentiate the views by those who had voting privileges and those who did not?

**Edit:** Confused by the outpouring of downvotes.  Please leave a comment.  To me the idea seems entertaining.

Comment: Seems like this wouldn't necessarily denote which is better. There would probably be many convoluting factors. I'd be willing to bet this rating would have significant differences between tags.

Comment: So a question that brought in 10s of thousands of redditors without accounts to vote is suddenly low quality? Not everyone that can view can vote.

Comment: Plus, questions that are ranked highly on Google would get a bunch of views and few upvotes, even if they're very helpful. You'd also have to factor in low view questions; questions with 2 views and 1 upvotes would be rather difficult to beat on this metric.

Comment: @MikePrecup There would have to be some thresholds.

Comment: @MartijnPieters True, but I'd guess that scenario isn't the norm.  Often times questions with lots of activity aren't google search material, and are mostly of interest to the SO community.

Comment: On the converse, it might also be entertaining to see questions that have extremely negative percentages.

Comment: Perhaps this should be rephrased as something like: a query to find what questions were primarily of interest to the SO community, as opposed to the broader public. I agree it seems interesting, I wonder if the downvotes are from people thinking this is a quality metric.

Comment: @Doc: not really; view counts say nothing about quality, really.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm not arguing that quality has anything to do with it.

Comment: @Doc: what is the point if thus being a feature request then? What are you trying to do with that ratio? View count and voting patterns are only loosely connected.

Comment: # of views has no relevance to # of votes, therefore any type of conclusion you try to draw from that data is meaningless. (For instance, if I search for a problem I'm having and find a possibly relevant existing question, and I view the question and it turns out not to actually be relevant, I've viewed but not voted on the question. Irrelevant increase in views w/o a vote.)

Comment: I believe the downvotes are for [tag:feature-request]. Perhaps if you tagged it as [tag:support], you will have different response. I'm trying to write a query in SEDE, but it seems the upvotes/downvotes are not disclosed, only a total score is available.

Comment: @KenWhite Re: irrelevant increase in views w/o a vote:  That's the idea.  The  ratio for that question has thus gone down.  What meaning that can be drawn from that ratio is vague, but there is still meaning. (In your case, it was not a good match for your keyword.  Perhaps it contains a number of keywords that seem meaningful for your query, but the content was meaningless.  It is at least loosely correlated to keyword authority.)

Comment: @KenWhite In any case, why is it so fascinating to look at these? http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/217695

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for fun, here is a [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/217612) for SEDE to *calculate the ratio of score-to-view for good-er questions (total score above <s>25</s> 50)*

Here are the top 5 results by ratio: (as of currently written)

- [ZCML allowed_attributes corresponding method in five.grok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834640): 658 views, score of 63 = 9.5744%
- [std::vector performance regression when enabling C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20977741): 1811 views, score of 162 = 8.945%
- [Implementing a non-terrestrial calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21940059): 1009 views, score of 85 = 8.4241%
- [Midi Timing Issues with Delphi ASIO VST and MiniHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547783): 652 views, score of 54 = 8.2822%
- [Getting MSDN PeerChannel "SecureChat" running on Windows Server 2008 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142617): 669 views, score of 55 = 8.2212%

Then, by view count (popularity):

- [What is the best comment in source code you have ever encountered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618): 1892635 views, score of 360 = 0.0190%
- [How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945): 1521808 views, score of 2239 = 0.1471%
- [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093): 1425960 views, score of 2702 = 0.1894%
- [How do I undo the most recent local commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358): 1373407 views, score of 4946 = 0.3601%
- [How do I check whether a checkbox is checked in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712): 1301726 views, score of 1618 = 0.1242%

And lastly, by score (quality):

- [Why is processing a sorted array faster than processing an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809): 467789 views, score of 8407 = 1.797%
- [How to modify existing, unpushed commit messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123): 840528 views, score of 5583 = 0.6642%
- [How do I undo the most recent local commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358): 1373407 views, score of 4946 = 0.3601%
- [What is the correct JSON content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816): 803148 views, score of 4471 = 0.5566%
- [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242): 719351 views, score of 4279 = 0.5948%

I can't really make any conclusions, but "interesting" questions (by your definition) definitely cannot be measured only by ratio, as I don't understand what they were talking about.

P.S I hope this answer won't bring meta effect to those questions and thus, skewing the result furthermore.

Comment: Great answer. I wonder if there is some way to differentiate views by those who had voting privileges. Re: "as I don't understand what they were talking about": perhaps including a tag in the predicate would give them meaning for you.

Answer (score 4):

[Like Martijn said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268660/views-vs-upvotes-score-for-questions-answers/268667#comment77752_268660), except that the problem isn't limited to Redditors (which, you rightly point out, is a rare case).

In fact, the *overwhelming majority* of the traffic on Stack Overflow does not have the requisite privileges to vote on questions (or answers), so this metric would be close to useless, if not downright misleading.

There are tons of people who come across a question (counting as a view), find it useful, and profit from the knowledge that they have gained. But the majority of those people aren't registered users—they just happened across the page from their favorite web search engine. They would probably upvote if they could, but no one takes the time to create an account just to upvote a single question. Most of our traffic consists of unregistered <strike>oglers</strike> Googlers.

To be honest, there have been times I've been taken to Stack Overflow from shared computers (or even virtual machines) and been far too lazy (or security-conscious) to log into my account just so that I can upvote a question or answer. If I remember, I'll go back later and upvote. But I don't always remember. At any rate, even if I do so, that would be 2 page views and only 1 upvote—wrong.

Comment: @Bart: Who got the glasses first? Cody or you?

Comment: It seems like it could be argued that since the vast majority don't have voting privileges, their traffic could generally be omitted from analysis.  In other words, it seems like traffic that doesn't have voting privileges should generally be about the same percentage for most questions (barring outliers of course). (I realize that traffic sourcing is a bit more complex than that, but I'm generalizing.)   It would be ideal if you could differential the viewers by voting rights.  In short: it doesn't matter.

Comment: The real question might be "which one is the sockpuppet?" @InfiniteRecursion.