# Reward quality not popularity and reward answers provided for niche questions

Tags: feature-request

By now for the question to receive a lot of upvotes it must touch a popular topic. There's of course nothing wrong with it, but it drives SO into a site dedicated to noob audience. There's no fun to answer less popular questions, because such question has low views, so it does not have chance to receive a lot of upvotes if any. Such answer is seen as "worse" one by a system, even if it perfectly explains problem and is beautifully written.

IMO it would be good if questions and answers were rated using `votes/view` ratio. This could be additional mechanism to normal reputation system that could be interpreted as *quality* of the answer/question, while the standard one can be interpreted as *significance*. For example if question has `10` views and `5` upvotes it has `0.5` ratio, meaning it is a high quality question. Another question may have `100` views and `20` upvotes, so it it more significant but of less quality (`0.2` ratio). Same with answers. This can bring fun to answering less popular questions and highlight question which are good, but from different perspective than purely popularity based one.

Comment: Perhaps you should try to answer because you can help, not because you get upvotes?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268685/922184

Comment: @MartijnPieters then why upvotes exist? If you should answer because you can help, not because you get upvotes then why they exist? It's of course for fun and IMO there's no fun if good question/answer is seen as worse by a system only because it does not touch popular topic.

Comment: @doc: to rank answers relative to one another, within the context of the question. If you are here for upvotes, then stick to popular topics.

Comment: @MartijnPieters and to rank questions. So my proposal is to rank them from different perspective. No I'm not here for upvotes.

Comment: @doc: when comparing questions, compare them within a tag then. But even there that's comparing apples to pears as posting time (day of the week, hour of the day, major holiday somewhere in the world or not) all influence how a question is received. There is little point in trying to make such comparisons, as views can vary widely for an even wider range of factors.

Comment: This sounds very similiar to Reddit's "fuzzing" system, and I don't think it should be implemented in SO.

Comment: @MartijnPieters sorry but I don't undestand you. To me if question receives many votes I look at it as it is possibly interesting. Same with answer. It is an indicator of some kind. Additional indicators can bring additional perspective. Of course it may depend on the day of the week or even weather, but it's not to measure things with a precision of 1000 decimal places.

Comment: @doc: yet you are proposing that reputation earned becomes a direct function of the view count. I am saying that a view count is not something you can rely on to carry any meaning. Which is why we stick with reputation coming from votes only. Much simpler, works just fine.

Comment: @MartijnPieters `views/votes` ratio does not depend on the view count! That's why it can measure quality of the question rather than standard system, which rewards questions with higher view count (more views = higher chance to receive vote).

Comment: @doc: come again? How does a views/votes ratio *not* depend on the view count? The ratio is *meaningless* without the views part.

Comment: @doc: and there is another downside to your proposal: all the rep whores will flock to the low-view-count tags, flooding those with crap, as a vote there counts for more rep than popular tags. Only, there won't be as many people vetting those low-quality answers in low-view-count answers, so the quality levels go down.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the same way as velocity does not depend on the path that you travelled. If you compare speed of two cars you don't take into account the path they travel, even if path is a part required to measure velocity.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was thinking of making this feature as **additional** to normal reputation system. It would work just as another perspective. If it's hard to implement then I understand it's bad idea. Thought it's relatively low cost.

Comment: @doc *"This can bring fun to answering less popular questions"* It seems that your premise is that most people don't find answering less popular questions to be fun, and that this is a problem. I think this premise is fundamentally flawed (both parts of it). However, if you *are* the type of person that only has fun answering popular questions, then the easiest solution is to just only answer popular questions. There will be others who have a different idea of "fun" to fill in the gaps that you don't want to fill in. Both views are fine and work together without issues.

Comment: @JasonC if there were no reputation system at all then I would agree. But since it exists it affects human mind. You may believe opposite, but reward and punishment system affects human mind. That's why communist society didn't work (there is no reward for your work).

Comment: @doc But *well-written* non-popular questions *do* get good answers frequently (just not by *you* personally, which again, is totally OK). Empirical observations counter your premise.

Comment: @JasonC And on what premise you claim it? Just take a look how many questions on SO are unanswered.

Comment: @doc Well, my *hypothesis* is that the majority of unanswered questions are unanswered not because they are good questions on non-popular topics that users don't feel motivated to answer, but because they are generally poor questions, or they are difficult questions that either have no answer or a knowledgeable user has not seen yet (where a solution to the latter would be to improve visibility of said question, not to provide incentive since incentive does not help if nobody who sees the question knows the answer).

Comment: I think your proposal would carry more weight if you could provide evidence that good, unanswered questions stay unanswered because there is no motivation to answer them, rather than because they have not yet been seen by a person who has an answer. Examples are always good. As it stands I do not see a clear or convincing argument that your proposal would solve the problem you intend to solve (or that the problem exists). That's not to say it doesn't, you just haven't presented the case.

Comment: @JasonC if unanswered question has low view count, but it receives upvotes, then it is probably good question and that's the point. Currently you can't even filter questions in such way, so the chance that such question will be seen by user who knows the answer is very low.

Comment: @doc While you can't sort by views, http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes can help (the click path to get there is unanswered -> votes (see also "no answers", since "unanswered" means none accepted, even if some are posted). You can also click "unanswered tags" on the right or just type "[tag]" in the search box in that view to filter by tags. You could also run queries on http://data.stackexchange.com/ for study purposes (not great for normal search, obviously, but good for collecting data).

Comment: @JasonC is it worth an effort to answer these questions? Probably not if author does not show any signs of life. The problem is that as SO became big site questions are falling down really fast in the queue. Receiving satisfying, deep answers is more difficult than in the past.

Comment: @doc I think it's worth an effort. The only reason I answer questions at all is to learn something new or to keep my mind sharp (for example, I'm primarily a C++ programmer, professionally, which would not be apparent in my SO activity). If it helps a bunch of other people out in the process, it's a bonus side effect.

Comment: @JasonC 1/2 right, but since new questions appear every 10 seconds, you will more likely choose new question, because you know you can help and receive upvote. My point is: you and whole community could learn more if high quality questions, but for narrower audience - requiring more expertise level, were highlighted. Currently such questions sink in the ocean of common problems. They receive many upvotes, because they attract broad audience.

Comment: 2/2 By an example take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23501476/how-php-core-is-handling-client-connections/23501583#23501583. Its educational value is enormously high for those who are deep in PHP. But such question will be overshadowed by something like "How to get the client IP address in PHP?" or how to sort an array, because noob questions have broader audience.

Comment: @doc I see what you mean, but the question you linked to has two good answers (including yours). What is the issue with that particular example? Do you feel it requires more answers? Do you feel *your* answer (or the other one there) is not a "satisfying, deep" answer?

Comment: @JasonC the problem is If I were on the site 2 minutes later I would certainly overlook this question. Once I overlook it, it's impossible to get there and learn something or provide answer. Lately I don't even want to look at queue because it's flooded with junk. Tired of this.

Answer (score 4):

Questions and answers with high upvotes are not "better" than those with low votes. They're *more useful*. The fact that answers to common questions in popular tags are useful to a lot more people means that they deserve more upvotes. If you only answer questions in the [erlang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/erlang) tag, you're not going to be able to compete on reputation with people answering in the [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) or [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tags. That's why each tag has a [leader board](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/erlang/topusers).

Comment: Devil's advocate (because I don't really support the proposal): You could argue that a higher vote:view ratio means "more useful", though. For example, a very *low* vote:view ratio with high views might mean it's a very common problem but was not a great solution (or a great question) - i.e. it's highly *misleading*. On the other hand a high vote:view ratio with a low view count could mean it's a great answer to an uncommon problem. You are describing "more people = more useful", but "more relatively useful for a specific topic" isn't unreasonable. I definitely don't like the proposal though.

Comment: @JasonC "more relatively useful" is not the same thing as "more useful." If not very many people find something useful, then it's just not very useful.

Comment: Yep it can be called usefulness and I'm not denying this. How much do I need to repeat that I was thinking about this as additional feature. Just like leader board exists and I don't care (it's useless for me, but maybe useful to someone else). And your points are one way to look at it. Another way to look at it is that beautifully written answer or great question, but for narrow audience, deserves high rating too.

Comment: @doc Perhaps it does. But "to deserve" and "to get" are very different things.

Comment: Even within many tag leader boards, it is currently hard to compete with spurious highly popular question answerers. See this thread: [Can the list of Top Users for low(er) traffic tags be improved?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373985/can-the-list-of-top-users-for-lower-traffic-tags-be-improved/374135#374135)

Answer (score 1):

> By now for the question to receive a lot of upvotes it must touch a
>   popular topic. There's of course nothing wrong with it, but it drives
>   SO into a site dedicated to noob audience.

That is not true at all. The general notion is that the more useful something is, the more upvotes it will receive. So of course something that appeals to a wider audience will be more useful to more people. By definition, something that is niche will be less useful to most people.

However, this site has hundreds or thousands of users who are professionals/enthusiasts/experts in the popular tags. They are not isolated to only niche tags, and niche tags aren't always full of high quality questions/answers. The site already has facilities to benefit answerers of niche tags. Bounties are one of those ways.

If you're only on here to gain rep, then feel free to post answers in one of the more popular tags. Otherwise, consider realigning your goals and posting useful answers because you want to contribute to the site.

Comment: I'm not here for reputation, but somehow current system discourages me from providing answers to questions with low views. It's probably something with human psychology. System gives you a feeling that answering specific, very technical question is like "no one cares". The impact on SO is that some questions that could have answers don't have them. I think that paradoxically perception of the whole site usefulness is related to those niche questions. Just like hospital seems to be useful not because it can cure 1000 people with flu, but because it can cure 1 man with very rare disease.