# When should you upvote a simple factual question that solves your problem?

Tags: discussion, voting

When making a simple Google search that ends up in Stack Overflow, it makes sense to upvote an answer if it solves your problem. Since I'm happy that I don't have to wait for an answer by asking the question myself, I'm glad that the question was asked, so I upvote the question as well. Is that the right way to go, even if it's a simple question? Apparently above 50% and below 100% of the people do the same, e.g. [How does one configure Notepad++ to use spaces instead of tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197812/how-does-one-configure-notepad-to-use-spaces-instead-of-tabs)

Comment: Where do you get those percentages from? The question has been viewed 80K+ times and has < 200 upvotes, meaning fewer than 1 in 400 visitors found it upvote-worthy.

Comment: @CodeCaster percentages of people who upvoted the accepted answer, I assume.

Comment: More view to vote stats - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268660/views-vs-upvotes-score-for-questions-answers... summary: voting from 10% of viewers is almost non-achievable, and general questions get way less than 1% of viewers to vote. Definitely nowhere close to 50%-100% mentioned in the post (also OP may mean some other ratio).

Comment: Can a question solve a problem? And what are simple/not simple questions?

Comment: @CodeCaster what DontPanic said.

Comment: @Trilarion https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Albert I still don't see 50-100% there.

Comment: @CodeCaster 178 upvotes to the linked question is above 50% of 302 (the upvotes for the answer)

Comment: Oh, you mean it like that. You can't just say that though, for all we know the question-upvoters didn't upvote the answers or vice versa.

Comment: _"upvote a simple factual question that solves your problem"_ -  Note that the _question_ did not solve your problem, one of the _answers_ did.  Upvote the question only if it's a good question in its own right.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The tooltip for an upvote is "This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear." If it helped solve your problem, then clearly it *is* useful (at least to you).

As long as the question doesn't have obvious policy violations (e.g. rude or abusive, clearly off-topic) and is reasonably formulated, the answer is "always." The fact that it's a simple factual question doesn't really matter - it was still useful to you either way.

Answer (score 44):

Upvote the question if you think it's a good question.

The fact that the answer solved your problem does not mean that the question was any good. It's theoretically possible for a bad question to get a great answer ([you can earn a badge for creating one of those answers, actually](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal)), and I don't think we should upvote bad things.

Of course it makes perfect sense to upvote the answer if it was helpful, but judge the question on its own merits and vote (or not vote) accordingly. Chances are, if the answer was really useful, the question is probably just fine, but the usefulness of the answer should not exempt the question from the usual quality standards.

Hopefully if the question actually *is* bad you can edit it to make improvements. But sometimes, it does something like [insist that the answer that just helped you doesn't work without saying why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603698/force-an-integer-to-be-at-least-2-digits-long), or [ask people to convert code from one language to another instead of asking an actual question at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27034517/go-net-http-request), and I don't know of a good way to improve questions like that without completely rewriting them.

Maybe upvoting a question will help it be more searchable (I'm not actually sure how that works) but if you found it through Google to begin with, it probably doesn't need any more help being searchable.

Comment: "it's a good question" - I think it is quite bad explanation of when one should upvote. If I found question that I'd ask myself than indeed the question is good and useful *for me*. I suspect by saying "good" you mean "shows research, clear, MCVE,..." and completely exclude whether question is useful for person looking for answer to particular problem. Some samples of questions that you believe should not be upvoted (i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string-in-c) could make this answer better.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I didn't include an explanation of what I think makes a "good" question, because I think that's a somewhat separate and considerably larger topic. I agree that if the answer helps me solve my problem, then the question is _useful_ to me in terms of helping me find the useful answer. But I'm not going to upvote it just because of that if that's its only redeeming quality. I've found useful answers on questions that were enough of a mess that I was impressed that the answerer was even able to figure out what was being asked.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I honestly don't really care that much about research effort or MCVE, as long as the question is clear. And I agree that sample questions would make this answer better. I will look for some.

Comment: It seems to me that some of the attributes that are associated with a question being "good" are focused on it being answerable.  While others are on its applicability to other people and related problems.  Certainly some overlap as answered questions are obviously more useful than unanswered ones, and the detail that makes a question answerable can help in allowing others to understand it and if it applies to their situation.  But at least some criteria (research) seem more moot in a clearly answered question, while others (edge case or reoccurring) are more prominent.

Comment: My problem with "good" is it just does not explain "me" as person who just found question they tried to ask to decide whether it should be voted up or down (assuming they decided to vote). On one hand this is the same one as they would ask (and hence quite reasonable at least, maybe even brilliant) on other hand there is that "good SO question" requirement. Need to think "I'm complete idiot because I wanted to ask such an awful useless question so it deserves downvotes" just does not feel right to me.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I don't think I actually disagree with you that much. If someone asks pretty much the same question I have and I find a useful answer on it, I generally _do_ upvote the question as well. All I'm saying is, just because I found the answer I needed does _not_ mean that the question was the same thing I would have asked, and to me the upvote is not automatic - it still depends on the quality of the question.

Comment: There is no objective definition of what is a good / bad question or good / bad answer.  It would be impossible to come up with one.  But that is OK.  Voting allows people to express their opinions (subjective), and then other people can treat vote counts as an *indication*.  "N people thought this was good" is helpful for both other readers, and for ranking search results.  It is not perfect, but it is practical.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that voting is free. You can vote as you want.

I don't see why simple factual questions would deserve more or less votes than complex factual questions.

I adhere to a useful, (re)search, clear measure and try to reward questioners as well as answerers. They are virtual unicorn points anyway.

Probably the order of the questions if sorted by score does contain some information because highly upvoted questions may be very interesting, important, contain good answers, are easily understandable, clear, useful, showing (re)search, ... so that's something.

It's probably not a wrong way to go.