# What to do about downvoted question with upvoted answer?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43413929/how-to-generate-a-unique-key-for-an-array) question which received multiple downvotes and a close vote, but which also has an accepted answer with upvotes.

This is confusing since a downvote (to me) indicates that the community feels the question contributes nothing useful in its current state.  With that in mind I figured I'd just remove it, rather than leave it in limbo waiting to get closed and downvoted even more.

But the system won't allow it:

> We do not recommend deleting questions with answers because doing so deprives future readers of this knowledge.

My feeling is, the community doesn't like the question so why should I be compelled to leave it up?

Comment: You can [contact SO](http://stackoverflow.com/contact), select "My question or answer did not meet quality standards", and ask to remove it

Comment: @AlonEitan - thanks - do you think that's the right thing to do?  I know this is subjective, but it's confusing to me that the community can place value on an answer but not on a question.  I guess I'm just trying to weigh whether or not there's value here since the response is mixed.

Comment: Well, years ago I asked 2 questions that I was ashamed of (Basically asking for a libraries recommendations), so I contact SO and asked to remove them. What they did was to "disconnect" them from my account. My answers didn't got downvotes though. but I guess they will help you anyway

Comment: @AlonEitan good point - I've inlined it in my answer.

Comment: *My feeling is, the community doesn't like the question so why should I be compelled to leave it up?* Because at this point you can't delete it without also removing content that the community has marked as useful. People won't answer if they know their work can get wiped out. It does mean that situations like this can happen where some people think a question isn't good but others feel it's worth answering.

Comment: @BSMP - I realize we're dealing with human beings here, but logically if the community feels an answer is useful, then it follows that the question must be useful since otherwise the answer wouldn't exist.  It doesn't quite make sense to take a rep hit on a question that has resulted in something the community deems useful.  Maybe questions should receive .5 upvotes per upvote on answers or something.  I *always* make a point to upvote the question if I find useful answers and I think this is something that often gets overlooked by voters.

Comment: @billynoah unconditional upvoting of question you've found useful is controversial topic at this moment (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347826/when-should-you-upvote-a-simple-factual-question-that-solves-your-problem)... Note that you are mixing "community found q useful" and "community found q answerable". Upvotes on answers give you hint that question *may be useful* but by itself don't mean much for usefulness of the q only potential expectation that q will be edited in shape. View count over time may be better indication of overall usefulness.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - thanks for pointing that out.  To me it's a simple matter of the fact that I got useful information as a result of the question, therefore I feel they should be rewarded.  I ***do*** read the questions so if it's horrific I'd either be inclined to edit, comment, or in some rare situations not upvote it.  So I guess my policy isn't exactly *unconditional*, but more often than not, they're getting an upvote.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In general you should try to improve question so it becomes on-topic/high quality.

If you really feel question is not useful - flag for moderator attention. Note that you need to provide *very good reason* as moderators rarely remove valid content and especially up-voted answers. As Alon Eitan [commented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347934/what-to-do-about-downvoted-question-with-upvoted-answer/347936#comment465725_347934) moderators can disassociate question from your account instead of deletion in some cases.

For your particular case I don't think you can do much about "compute unique hash" question - it is asked many times for all variations of algorithms and languages already. Maybe showing some understanding what hashing is could improve the question (but it also will invalidate the answers)... Maybe mentioning [perfect hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Perfect_hashing)  and result of [search for it](https://www.bing.com/search?q=unique%20hash%20perfect%20site%3Astackoverflow.com) like "I heard about perfect hash function and it seem what I need." with links...

Answer (score 3):

You should leave the question, and not get too bothered about downvotes.

1. There are some in the community that are quick to judge a question as 'bad', without trying to understand your question in your context. Most good lads here would seek clarification in the comments, suggest an alternate perspective to your problem, or edit the question if it's salvageable.
2. When you get an upvoted answer, it means someone has understood the way you have expressed your question. **There is a good chance someone else in the future would interpret a problem the same way you did,** and the solution may be relevant to them.
3. Trust in the SEO that bad questions would get buried in the abyss, and good questions will rise to the top.

Most, if not all questions can be improved to some extent (even good ones). Having room for improvement should not be the yardstick for the quality of the question. As long as you've done your due diligence, ask from the perspective of learning (instead of trying to get others to do your dirty work), and your question can be reasonably understood (has a main point, some context, readable), it's a good question.